# The units digit of $1!+2!+3!+4!!+5!!+\dots+k\underset{\left \lfloor \sqrt{k} \right \rfloor \text{ times}}{\underbrace{!!!\dots!}}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial, ceiling-and-floor-functions

For natural numbers $n\ge m$, let $n\underset{m \text{ times}}{\underbrace{!!!\dots!}}=n(n-m)(n-2m)(n-3m)\dots$ where all factors are natural numbers (we exclude $0$ and negative factors).

***Question:***

> What is the units digit of $1!+2!+3!+4!!+5!!+\dots+k\underset{\left
> \lfloor \sqrt{k} \right \rfloor \text{
> times}}{\underbrace{!!!\dots!}}+\dots+1992\underset{44 \text{
> times}}{\underbrace{!!!\dots!}}$? ($\left \lfloor \cdot \right
> \rfloor$ denotes the floor funtion).

---

***My Attempt (Is wrong as  Peter Foreman commented below):***

Consider the first $9$ terms:

$1!+2!+3!+4!!+5!!+6!!+7!!+8!!+9!!!$

$=1+2+6+8+15+48+105+384+162=731$

Each of the remaining terms includes at least on factor that ends with $0$. Therefore, the each term ends with $0$.

Hence the units digit of the given expression is equal to the units digit of the sum of the first $9$ terms. So, $1$ is the units digit of the given expression.

---

Peter Foreman said: "$17!!!!=9945$". This showed me that my attempt is wrong. Thanks  Peter Foreman.

---

Any help would be appreciated. THANKS.

Comment: @PeterForeman ,, yeah , you are right that I am wrong.

Comment: It's also going to be non-zero whenever the number of ! is a multiple of 5 and n isn't.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Right. So can not we solve this problem by ordinary methods?

Comment: I'd write a program that spits out the first hundred unit digits and stare at it for a while.  The pattern will be easier to prove when you know what it is.

Comment: It's $1$. (I don't know how to prove it without computation)

Comment: @Vepir how did you know? Did you use a program?

Answer (score 2):

When $k \geq 25$ and the floor part $p$ of $k^{0.5}$ is coprime with $10$, the unit digit of $k’=k! \ldots !$ is $0$ (there is an even number in $k,k-p$ and one divisible by $5$ in $k!!!!!$).

When $k \geq 25$ and $p \wedge 10=2$, there is going to be a number divisible by $5$ in $k,k-p,k-2p,k-3p,k-4p$, and $k’$ is divisible by $5$ and congruent to $k$ mod $2$, so the unit digit of $k’$ is $5$ if $k$ is odd and $0$ if $k$ is even.

When $k \geq 25$ and $p \wedge 10=5$, then $k(k-p)$ is even, so $k’$ is even. The congruence mod $5$ is trickier: $k’$ is congruent to $k^r$ mod $5$, where $r$ is the number of factors in he product (ie $r-1$ is the floor part of $(k-1)/p$, so $r$ is either $p$, $p+1$ or $p+2$).

When $10 | p$, as above, $k’$ is congruent to $k^r$ mod $10$.

Note that everything depends only on the unit digit of $k$, $p$ and $r$: when $p$ is set, and $p \wedge 10=2$, the sum of any four $k’$ corresponding to consecutive $k \geq 25$ vanishes mod $10$.

When $p,r$ are set and $p \wedge 10=5$, the sum of any five $k’$ corresponding to consecutive $k \geq 25$ is always divisible by $10$.

When $p,r$ are set and $p \wedge 10=10$, the sum of any ten $k’$ corresponding to consecutive $k \geq 100$ is congruent to $3$ mod $10$ if $4|r$ and $5$ mod $10$ otherwise.

So all we need now is time for processing all integers from $1$ to $1992$.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by the notations $k'$, $p \wedge 10=10$,...? Thank you very much.

Comment: $\wedge$ is the gcd. $p$ is the floor part of $\sqrt{k}$. $r-1$ is the floor part of $(k-1)/p$. $k’=k(k-p)(k-2p)\ldots(k-(r-1)p)$.

Comment: So this problem is not solvable unless we find the units digit of all $1992$ terms, right? Is not there any method to solve it?

Comment: The answer outlines many possible shortcuts, but why would you expect there to be an instant solution without any calculation?